# How do I create a dummy variable within a range of values in R?

Tags: r

I need to create a dummy variable where if 20≤dummy≤40, it reads '1', and '0' otherwise. I think I am having a brainfart, but I cannot seem to do it.

I currently have:

```
dummy_x <- ifelse(x<=40, 1, 0)
```

which works, however:

```
dummy_x <-ifelse(20<=x<=40, 1, 0)
```

does not. If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, my man. It's been a long day

Comment: `20 <= x <= 40` isn't valid R syntax. The closest thing to it is probably `between()` from the `dplyr` package: `ifelse(dplyr::between(x, 20, 40), 1, 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to split the second `ifelse` into two conditions like `ifelse(x>=20 & x <=40, 1, 0)`